# Why is Webdriver.findElements missing elements?

Tags: selenium

I am using this little bit of code to return values from a screen:

```
    // find label-placeholder-text by innerHTML
private static final String labelPlaceholderTextClass="label-placeholder-text";
// get 'for' value
// get field with that id
// print value from that field?
public static String returnValueFromPlaceholderText(WebDriver driver, String identifier) {
    myPrint(thisClass + " Find value using identifier = '" + identifier + "'");
    List<WebElement> placeholders = driver.findElements(By.className(labelPlaceholderTextClass));
    myPrint(thisClass + " placeholders count: " + placeholders.size());
    for (WebElement element : placeholders) {
        String text = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        if (text != null) {
            text = text.trim();
            myPrint(thisClass + " text: " + text);
            if (text.equals(identifier)) {
                myPrint(thisClass + " found: " + text);
                String forId = element.getAttribute("for");
                myPrint(thisClass + " id of input field =  " + forId);
                WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.id(forId));
                getAllAttributes(element, driver);
                text = inputField.getAttribute("value");
                myPrint(thisClass + " " + identifier + " value = " + text);
                return text;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

On my webpage, I have a number of these 'label-placeholder-text' fields.

This one it is finding and successfully returning the value:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-ellipsis-global 
form-control-readonly" id="gwt-uid-2431" data-empty="false" readonly="">

<label class="label-placeholder-text" for="gwt-uid-2431"> Last activity:</label>
```

Sample output:

```
utils.Common                             Find value using identifier = 'Last activity:'
utils.Common                             placeholders count: 1
utils.Common                             text: Last activity:
utils.Common                             found: Last activity:
utils.Common                             id of input field =  gwt-uid-2431
utils.Common                            get all attributes.
{for=gwt-uid-2431, class=label-placeholder-text}
utils.Common                             Last activity: value = 19 hours ago
```

But it is not finding these:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-ellipsis-global 
form-control-readonly" id="gwt-uid-2473" data-empty="false" readonly="">
<label class="label-placeholder-text" for="gwt-uid-2473">Reported Date</label>
```

Any ideas why it is only finding 1 of the elements?

Comment: Are you sure the second label has already taken the place in the DOM when driver.findElements is getting executed?

Comment: The elements are all clearly visible on the screen with values.

Comment: Add some delay before running driver.findElements. Try to debug.

Comment: @Ratmir Asanov - spot on!

Comment: If putting in a delay caused the test to succeed, you'll want to be careful how you wait. Sleeps can cause flakey tests that are hard to debug, instead you should use explicit waits, that wait for something specific on the page to happen that indicates it's ready to be used.

Comment: @mrfreester - I do not think explicit wait would work in this instance, as I do not know what I am looking for till I get it.

Comment: @SteveStaple sure, but are you aware of any structural changes to the web site you can check for that indicates your data is there? For example, some table having more than one row, a specific div having a child with a specific attribute etc... You must resist the urge to add sleeps! If you have more than about 5ish in your test suite, you'll find that it just turns into a maintenance mess with a bunch of manual reruns because tests just won't pass consistently... Or if you make your sleeps way too long, you have to wait forever for the tests to complete. Not worth it in either case.